# Unable to Install gems on Mavericks using bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have been trying for sometime, searched in google but no luck. When I do a `bundle install`, I get the below error.

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies....
Using rake 10.4.2
Using i18n 0.7.0
Installing json 1.8.3 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/rajuaralikatti/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150927-24454-1bfrcxj.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean


Agreeing to the Xcode/iOS license requires admin privileges, please re-run as root via sudo.



make "DESTDIR="


Agreeing to the Xcode/iOS license requires admin privileges, please re-run as root via sudo.



make failed, exit code 69

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/rajuaralikatti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@smart_farm/gems/json-1.8.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/rajuaralikatti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@smart_farm/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.2.0-static/json-1.8.3/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing json (1.8.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.3'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I have also run
`xcode-select --install`

gcc `/usr/bin/gcc -> /usr/local/Cellar/apple-gcc42/4.2.1-5666.3/bin/gcc-4.2`

ruby version
`ruby 2.2.0p0`

Let me know if you need more information.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some trial and error, I was able to solve the issue. I had to install rails 4.2.0 first.

First I tried `gem install rails -v 4.2.0`

Got the following error

```
This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/rajuaralikatti/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150927-28698-1utu0vb.rb extconf.rb --use-system-libraries
checking if the C compiler accepts ... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/rajuaralikatti/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --help
    --clean
/Users/rajuaralikatti/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /Users/rajuaralikatti/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:571:in `block in try_compile'
    from /Users/rajuaralikatti/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:522:in `with_werror'
    from /Users/rajuaralikatti/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:571:in `try_compile'
    from extconf.rb:80:in `nokogiri_try_compile'
    from extconf.rb:87:in `block in add_cflags'
    from /Users/rajuaralikatti/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:621:in `with_cflags'
    from extconf.rb:86:in `add_cflags'
    from extconf.rb:337:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/rajuaralikatti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@smart_farm/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/rajuaralikatti/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@smart_farm/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.2.0-static/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/gem_make.out
```

Solved the problem with the following commands

```
gem uninstall nokogiri libxml-ruby
gem install nokogiri
gem install rails -v 4.2.0
bundle install
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you don't accept a licence. Try this

```
sudo xcodebuild -license
```